# Display a page based on javascript conditions

Tags: php, javascript, html, conditional-statements

I have a javascript condition statement on the basis of which i want to let the user access a page or block the user's access. I can do a redirect to that page in the if statement, but then i dont want the users to even directly access that page. That page contains HTML + PHP so i can even use session variables to block access directly, but php variables cant be directly set using javascript.

Is there any way so that i may block or allow access to that page on basis of this JS condition, either by setting cookies or a better way around?

```
    if (offset==foo){

    //allow access to the page

            }
            else {
                    alert("You are not allowed to use proxy!");
//block access to the page
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: any client side blocking can be easily bypassed

Comment: What you are asking is on client side...Whatever you do will NOT be secure this way... Wouldn't recommend you to follow this path...

Comment: I got you points. But i have to compare two values, one is in php variable and the other is in Javascript variable. So it was easier to put php variable into a javascript variable and do the comparison. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: what the variable name is, is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate answer to your question is to not even use javascript for this at all.

Javascript is run client-side, which means that the user has complete control over it. Therefore any security/blocking mechanisms placed in Javascript are very easy to get around.

Rather, since you're already using PHP for serve side scripting, move your security/auth mechanisms into the server PHP code. This is **far** more secure, and the appropriate way to handle the task.

Comment: I have to compare two values, one is in php variable and the other is in Javascript variable. Please suggest how to put the javascript variable's value into a php variable and then compare. If i am able to do this, then everything will be solved.

Comment: Why is this value in a javascript variable? Is it loaded from user input? If so either use AJAX or a form to post it to a PHP script and get it that way (don't forget sanity checks if you do that). If it's hardcoded in the JS, just move it into the PHP.

Comment: It is kind of hard coded in the js.  For moving it to php , is there any method other than submitting using a form?

Comment: your evasiveness makes it difficult to help you.